# How to install NPM end-user packages on NixOS?

Tags: nix, chown, nixos

Is there a way to install NPM command line tools on NixOS?

```
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-0-27:~/teros/ntrs-cli]# sudo npm i -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /nix/store/rhikjv5vlpa6vq4qkrszinwsaz1mda7p-nodejs-8.15.1/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /nix/store/rhikjv5vlpa6vq4qkrszinwsaz1mda7p-nodejs-8.15.1/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, access '/nix/store/rhikjv5vlpa6vq4qkrszinwsaz1mda7p-nodejs-8.15.1/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.
```

I assume because it's read-only, because I did run:

```
chown -R `whoami` nix/store/rhikjv5vlpa6vq4qkrszinwsaz1mda7p-nodejs-8.15.1
```

as an aside if someone knows how to install Node.js version 11 or 12 on nixos that'd be great.

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, please undo the permissions change (`chown`) you made. You should NEVER change the permissions of files in the Nix store `(/nix/store`).

To install NPM packages on NixOS use the corresponding Nix package, instead of using `npm -g ...`. NPM packages are under the `nodePackages` "namespace".

For example, to install typescript (`tsc`) edit `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
...

environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  ...

  nodePackages.typescript;
]

...
```

Then use `nixos-rebuild switch` to "install" the package.

You can install Node.js the same way. Use `nix search nodejs` to see the various versions you can install.

Comment: I tried to install browser-sync, but nix can't find it ...

Answer (score 11):

Instead Edit `~/.npmrc` so that it tells `npm` to install and find "global" packages in your home folder instead of the root location:

```sh
prefix=~/.npm-packages
```

now any time you run `npm i -g <some-package>` you will see that it will be installed inside of `~/.npm-packages`.

Now in your shell rc file (f.e. `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or similar), you'll need to update your `PATH` to include executables from the new location:

```sh
### Add NPM executables to your PATH so that they are available as commands:
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```

Often it is more convenient to manage ephemeral dependencies outside of the system-level package manager.

If you use something like `n` or `nvm` to manage specific node versions, you can do a similar thing by managing them in your home folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm config set prefix '~/mutable_node_modules'
```

This thread should be helpful:

- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/3393#issuecomment-50330167
- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/3393#issuecomment-187510024

Answer (score 0):

You can also install them with the usual `npm -i...`, just without the `-g` (global) paramater.

Answer (score 0):

looks like things may have changed a bit.
on fish shell with `node v16.15.0` and `nix (Nix) 2.8.1`. I just had to add `fish_add_path -g $HOME/.node_modules/bin` to my config.fish then `npm install -g <package>`.